# creating a array using Array constructor having only one number element

Tags: javascript, arrays

these are few examples of the Array constructor use.

````
var arr2 = new Array(50); // returns [50 empty elements]
var arr3 = new Array(1, 2, "three", 4, "five"); // returns [1, 2, 'three', 4, "five"]
var arr4 = new Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // returns [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] ```
````

if i want to construct an array with only one element say 4. `[4]` How do i construct using the array constructor? If i use `new Array(4)` it will construct an array of length 4 with four empty elements `[4 empty elements]`.

Comment: please post a test input and the desired output

Comment: Why not just write `var arr = [4]`?

Comment: i want to understand whether it's possible to construct an array with the array Constructor which has only one number element.

Comment: @aryansingh This is the reason why [`Array.of(4)`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) was created.

Comment: okay, didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, not possible. But I have never used the `Array` constructor (except as `new Array(n)` to construct a `n`-length array), and I don't think I have ever seen it used, so this is not a big loss. Use a literal when you need to specify a hard-coded array, use various `Array` (and other) methods to make arrays dynamically... and don't use `var` now that we have `const` and `let`.